# If $2^a=3^b$ find $\frac{a}{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I tried many different things but still couldn't solve it. Could you please give me a clue?

Comment: logarithms?${}$

Comment: Use logarithm..

Comment: Hint: take $\,\ell = {\rm log}_2\,$ of both sides to get $\, a = b\,\ell(3)\ $

Comment: See also [Prove that $\log_2 3$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2028881/242)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try taking the natural log of both sides. Remember that $\ln 2^a=a\ln 2$ and $\ln 3^b=b\ln 3$.

$$a\ln 2=b\ln 3$$

Now, you can use division to solve for $\frac a b$.

Answer (score 4):

$2^a = 3^b; \tag 1$

$\ln (2^a) = \ln (3^b); \tag 2$

$a \ln 2 = b \ln 3; \tag 3$

$\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}. \tag 4$